# Why does Windows 10 still automatically download, install updates and restart system despite I telling it not to?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, automatic-update

I hate Windows so much! Why does it decide to automatically download and restart when I have all settings to off?

[image]

I had a 5 GB download running at 200 kB/s for hours and hours and somewhere at 80% this stupid Windows thinks it can just update and then restart! The download was not resumable because it required some stupid log in and uses Google to log in so I can't script the log in either. I hate it so much! I lost other work over this stupid update too.

How can I once and for all stop Windows from automatically screwing me over whenever this thing wants to?

Comment: Not a single one of those settings would actually prevent updates from installing except if you were to pause updates until a certain date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I once and for all stop Windows from automatically screwing me
> over whenever this thing wants to?

You cannot actually stop Windows 10 Updates, but you can and should manage them.

You can set updates to occur in Off Hours. Set your work hours and Windows will prepare the update while you are working, give you a notification, and then update in non-working hours.

This works and I never lose work to Windows Updates.

[image]

This is the best overall way.

If you are looking at Windows updates, you can pause updates for a few days in advance of a heavy work session. I suggest doing this before starting a very large download.

Manage update and you will not lose anything.